# DateTime Oveload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to have this output in my label
example:April 20,2016
but I get 4/20/2016:1200:00:AM instead

I tried to modified it but can't figure this error out

> no overload for method takes 1 arguments
>   cause by this code

```
lblDate.Text = rdr.GetValue(4).ToString("MMMM d,yyyy");
```

This is the entire code.

```
 private void GetData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = MejOnlineManagementDB00;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT orderProdName,orderProdType,orderQuantity,orderStatus,orderDateOrdered
                                        FROM orders2
                                        WHERE orderCustomer='"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()+"'",con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lblProdName.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                lblProdType.Text = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                lblQuantity.Text = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                lblStatus.Text = rdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                lblDate.Text = rdr.GetValue(4).ToString("MMMM d,yyyy");
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the [Object.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This method, does not have arguments. If you want to convert it into a date, you might try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(rdr.GetValue(4).ToString())
lblDate.Text = dt.ToString("MMMM d,yyyy");
```

#### Edit:

Please note, that if the date column in your database contains null-values, the parse methode will throw an exception. So testing for null is mandatory.

```
String s = Convert.ToString(rdr.GetValue(4));
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
   DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);
   lblDate.Text = dt.ToString("MMMM d,yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `rdr.GetValue(int32)` method returns an `object` and not `DateTime`.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Parse your the returned value into a `DateTime` object and then use the `ToString` method.

Answer (score 1):

That will work only for DateTime value, you can convert the value in DateTime first:

```
lblDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr.GetValue(4)).ToString("MMMM d,yyyy");
```